# How to solidify edges

Tags: modeling, mesh, edges

I have a complex mesh with only vertices and edges that I want to solidify.

The problem is I just want to solidify edges (not any faces) to have some kind of fat wireframe model (i.e. just every edges being cylinders). Not a classic solidify.

How can I achieve that?

Here is my mesh:
[image: Solidify Edges]

Comment: If you want to see a comparison of the results on my mesh: - Left: [Beveling a Curve](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/8305/3013)
- Center: [Wireframe Modifier](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/8301/3013) with **0.5 Thickness** and a **Subsurf**
- Right: [Skin Modifier](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/8301/30139) with **0.5 Branch Smoothing** and a **Subsurf** ![Comparison](http://i.imgur.com/94W6emX.png) I end up using the middle one (wireframe). It looks pretty organic without changing the initial shape of the mesh.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/2838/599

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You could use the [*Skin Modifier*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/skin.html). After adding it to the object, it might appear fat and blobby, so to adjust the thickness you can <kbd>Tab</kbd> into *Edit* mode and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> to affect the thickness.

[image]

Another way is to just fill in the faces of your model and make use of the [*Wireframe modifier*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modifiers/Generate/Wireframe).

Comment: How do you add a skin modifier in Blender 2.8? Both of the links you posted are dead.

Comment: @AaronFranke updated the link. See https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/introduction.html

Comment: I tried the skin modifier to an object with only 448 edges (64 selected), but the Ctrl+A scaling was unusably slow. Can't I type a value instead of dragging the mouse to set the thickness?

Answer (score 29):

### **Beveling a Curve**

Another way you can achieve your goal is to convert your Mesh composed of edges and vetices into a Curve. Then you could add a Bevel to the Curve and have your result. Here are the steps:

1. Select your wireframe mesh
2. Convert the mesh to a curve by either of these methods:

   - <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> -> Curve from Mesh/Text
   - 3D Viewport Header -> Object -> Convert To -> Curve from Mesh/Text

   [image]
3. Next, since you said you want to have every edge be a cylinder, you should Add a circle curve:  <kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> -> Curve -> Circle

   [image]
4. Now select your wireframe and in the Object Properties window, click on the Curve tab, scroll down to the Geometry section and set Bevel Object to the circle you added in step 3 -- this circle will then define the shape of the edges:

   [image]
5. Now adjust the size of the circle curve so your mesh looks the way you want it to:

   [image]

Comment: Thanks for the nice post. It may be useful once. But the problem is it's hard to rework on it afterward.

Comment: Yes, also, if you zoom in on the corners, I noticed the cylinders of the edges don't join together like they do with the Skin Modifier or the Wireframe Modifier.

Comment: Actually, Binary, you can edit the mesh again, but I guess you do have to keep converting from curve to mesh in order to edit it easily.

Comment: @BinaryBrain Yes, now I see what you mean about hard to edit. Oh well.

Comment: Yes, modifiers are a lot more user-friendly for that.

Comment: nice information

Comment: Where are these options in Blender 2.8? Alt+C and Shift+A no longer perform these operations.

Answer (score 4):

**Blender 2.9**

In Blender 2.9+ (presumably already since 2.8) it works similar as described in Thom Blair III's answer, except that the extra step of adding a cicular curve is no longer necessary. A tube radius for the convered Curve can now be added directly in the Curve Tab under Geometry > Bevel > Depth. Works pretty well and fast.

Answer (score 0):

You can also automate @thom-blair-iii's answer using Geometry Nodes :

1. mesh to curve
2. curve to mesh + profile curve to give it a thickness.

https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/249070/14306