# Curve Bevel function, scale?

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

Is there a way to scale up the bevel object on one end of a curve, a little bit over each point?

I notice the vertex "weight" slider will tweak how much influence each vertex has on the others, is there something like this that can scale the bevel object up a little bit?

Preferably with the option to constrain X,Y,Z independently

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use a combination of seven non mutually-exclusive techniques to control bevel radius and sizes either globally or on a per-point basis.

1. For simple tubular bevels with a circular section, not using any *Bevel Objects*, you can directly use the global *Bevel Depth* radius property, from the *Curve* tab in the Properties Window to control uniform bevel depth cross all splines.

[image: Bevel Radiuse]

For curves using *Bevel Objects*:

[image: Bevel Objects]

2. **Scale a Bevel Object in Object Mode** for uniform scaling across the whole curve. If scaled in *Object Mode* you can share the same bevel geometry across multiple curves, but each at independent sizes. You can scale independently for each axis.

[image: Scale Bevel Object in Object Mode]

3. **Scale the Bevel Object in Edit Mode** to affect all curves using a bevel objects sharing that *Object Data* geometry. It also remains with applied and uniform scale in *Object Mode*. You can scale independently for each axis.

[image: Scale Bevel Object in Edit Mode]

4. **Control the Curve Weight on a per vertex basis** for precise size control over each point in the curve. In *Edit Mode* press <kbd>Alt+S</kbd> to adjust radius of selected vertex or use the *Radius* tool. This acts as a percentage factor over all above scaling methods, multiplying its value over the result of *Bevel Depth*, *Bevel Object* scale and *Taper Object*.

See [Radius on beveled curve incorrect](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/86873/radius-on-beveled-curve-incorrect/86903#86903) for more details.

[image]

5. **Turn on Proportional Editing** by pressing <kbd>O</kbd> key while in *EditMode* to control the vertex weight smoothly along the spline length.

[image: Proportional Editing Vertex Weight]

6. **Use Taper Objects** to have another curve object parametrically and non destructively define the radius of the bevel object along the curve. The *Taper Object* is mapped lengthwise along the X axis of the "tappared curve", using the $Y$ axis coordinates of each vertex on *Local Space* as multiplication factor for bevel radius.

[image: Taper Object]

7. Adjust bevel easing progression along vertex from the *Radius Interpolation* property on a per spline basis. You can choose from several fallof types to affect smoothing, like *Linear*, *Cardinal*, *BSpline* or *Ease*.

[image]

All above methods are multiplied to calculate a final combined scaling factor.

You cannot however control different scales independently on each axis on a per vertex basis. Non uniform bevels scales are only possible by scaling a whole *Bevel Object* so they are by definition always consistent across the whole curve.

If you require varying non uniform scale you may have to convert (a copy of) your curve object into a mesh and do that destructively afterwards.

Alternatively if you only require a simple tube with circular section, you may also use a mesh object with a *[Skin Modifier](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8300/how-to-solidify-edges/8301#8301)* which allows different factors for each axis.

Comment: wonderful! sometimes it is quite difficult to find the right technique in Blender without knowing the terminology beforehand. thank you!

Comment: still wondering if there's anybody clever enough to figure out a way to scale on single/constrained axis... or perhaps do this with a tapered object but i'm visualizing a need for two object tapers although I'm not sure. basically to form a tube that runs along x axis and then flares out in the y direction on one end, but it's part of something bigger and doing this with curves would help enormously

Comment: Fair enough, I don't think you'll be able to scale independently on each axis in Blender without converting to mesh first though, there simply is no functionality to support it.  You can look into some third party addons to ease the process, but they are always bound by blender's limitations https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Curve/Curve_Tools or https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xfOlvZNgDt0

Comment: I meant to post this addon instead but couldn't originally find it http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?225190-Bsurfaces-v1-5 and https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.64/Bsurfaces_1.5 Again you might be able to loft between different bevel curves, but not directly from a bezier curve object as blender doesn't allow it, though this addon might still make it easier

Comment: excellent! plenty of ideas here for my model