# Can you use curves to make a pretzel?

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

I want to make a pretzel but I can't seem to get a good idea of how to make one.
I am wondering if you can use a curve and then put it on full bevel.

Basically, is there a good way to shape it?

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Curves are probably not the best way to model this, you will have trouble getting smooth ends and squishing the overlapping parts with proper topology. Yet it is a totally acceptable method, if you are just looking for a quick and dirty solution.

[image]

Start with a bezier circle object, change all vertex handles to *Aligned* type, then erase one of the bottom quarters.

Move all but the bottom vertex to the side and duplicate them symmetrically around the X axis.

Connect the loose bottom vertex to the new half with <kbd>F</kbd> key.

[image]

Now extrude the two ends at the center making sure they extend in the correct direction, away from the opposite segment.

[image]

Spread both coinciding vertex at the center to the sides so the wont intersect, and move the corresponding handles slightly up or down to make both strings twist around each other, as if entangled.

Adjust both ends Z position so they stay resting above the ring.

[image]

Optionally use a *[Taper Object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58564/curve-bevel-function-scale/58567#58567)* to get a smooth thickness progression along the string. You can also adjust per vertex thickness with the *Radius* property.

[image]

Comment: if only you could make an array of metaballs...?

Comment: Well probably not directly, but there are many workarounds, like Particle systems, *Dupliverts*, *Dupliframes*, *Duplifaces*

Comment: awesome, that really helped! I am definitely looking for a more detailed and real looking one, but this is a great start! Thanks