# Creating rounded shape (ballon effect)

Tags: bezier-curves, extrude

I am trying to create this shape in 3d, like in a ballon effect:

[image]

I have extruded the bezier curves and i am modifying them to create the shape in 3D. But the shape gets weird and not smooth at all.

[image]

Is there any other way to make it look like this but similar to the original shape?
Thanks!

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/106457/can-you-use-curves-to-make-a-pretzel

Comment: Thank you for the comment! I can make the shape with equal width. The problem is when trying to make the ends a little smaller.. The shape doesn't stay smooth

Comment: You probably just need higher resolution. You may also need to adjust the Radius Interpolation. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58564/curve-bevel-function-scale/58567#58567 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/120085/looking-for-equivalent-of-fusion-360-sweep-with-path-and-guiderail-in-blender/120091#120091

Comment: Thank you very much for you help! I will try to make it work. I'm from Portugal too, so obrigada :)