# Looking for equivalent of Fusion 360 Sweep with Path and Guiderail in Blender

Tags: modeling, 3d-printing

I am newbie to Blender and totally loving it. My focus to date has been on modeling and 3D printing.  I was using Autodesk Fusion 360 but have moved all my projects to Blender except one. I created the attached Tea Light in Fusion using a Sweep with a Path and Guiderail on a Curve.  Trying to find the equivalent inside Blender. I got close using a combination of modifiers both with and without Bezier Curves but can't quite seem to lock it in. Wondering if anyone might have a suggestion.

[image: Tea Light Side View]
[image: Tea Light Top View]
[image: Tea Light Bottom View]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually do all this directly from a bezier curve object, mostly without any modifiers or destructive workflows.

You need the [classic three-bezier curve objects system](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58564/curve-bevel-function-scale):

1. One for the actual $Body$ of the Tea Light

[image]

2. One defining its $Section$,

[image]

3. And one has a *Taper Object* to adjust the radius expansion interactively.

[image]

Assign them all to the correct slot of your body object, then play around with the taper shape to control the profile of the light.

[image]

For the *Taper Object* $Y$ coordinates of the points control the scaling ratio. At 
$Y=1$ there is no deformation, bellow that it reduces radius, and above it increases.

[image]

You can use *Tilt* to rotate the base. Adjust interpolation settings to improve smoothness.

[image]

This may require a conversion to mesh to take care of the closed cap at the base. Alternatively if you prefer avoiding the destructive last step, use a mesh object with an *Array Modifier* and *Curve Modifier*, deformed along the same "Body" curve, then use an *End cap* representing the base.

Comment: Duarte, That's exactly what I was looking for and much simpler than what I was attempting to do. You could not have explained it better. Thank You So Much!!!!