# How can i thicken a path?

Tags: path

So i have made a path and i have no idea how to make it thicker, Normally with meshes you scale them with S, but its my first time doing something with paths so i have no idea how to make them thicker. I have tried the Solidify Modifier with no results. I have tried a multiple tutorials but all of them didnt for or were for 2.79 version of Blender. Or can i maybe make a Cylinder follow the path?

[image: Paths]

Comment: so I suppose your path is a bezier curve? If you select it, in the Properties panel > Object Data, you can choose Shape > Fill > Full, then in Geometry > Bevel, give it some Depth, Resolution, you can even determine a bezier shape as profile in the Bevel Object field, then if you select a vertex and press alt S you change the thickness of the path

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58564/curve-bevel-function-scale/58567#58567