# How do I make varying curve bevel?

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves, bevel

[image: varying bevel]

How do I approach to create a model like this?

Comment: if you want to use curves to make these parts you can vary their radius or use a taper object, but you can also simply model it with a mesh

Comment: Looks like you have the mesh object and want to boolean away a curve from the center.  Does this help? https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/58567/110840

Comment: what do you meam by simply model with a mesh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I do for such shape.

- Use a Bezier curve, in this example called "path to follow" for the general curving shape.
- Use a different Bezier curve, in this example called "bevel shape" for the shape you have drawn in red.
- Use a third Bezier curve, in this example called "taper" to control how the bevel tapers from one end of the path to the other.

After I've created the 3 curves, but before I tune them, I set the Object Data Properties for the "path to follow" curve by going to the object data properties for the curve and adding the "taper" curve to *Geometry* as the *Taper Object* and the adding the "bevel shape" Curve to *Bevel* as the *Object* after setting the Bevel type to *Object*:

[image: Object data properties showing geometry and bevel]

Here's a funky object I created this way

[image: funky object]

The "Path to follow"

[image: The path to follow curve]

The "taper"

[image: the taper curve]

and finally, the "bevel shape"

[image: The bevel]

Notice that for simplicity that they all sit on the same plane and have the same origin.  That's not required. Experiment to see what effect moving and rotating them has.

I *strongly* recommend giving the curves unique names.  It's very easy to screw up and use the wrong curve as the bevel or taper, or to apply bevel or taper to the wrong curves.