# Beam Modeling & Curve Geometry Bevel Custom Presets

Tags: modeling, interface, bezier-curves

I'm currently modeling a bridge and I have a lot of square beams to make. The quick dirty way I found is to use bezier curves and playing with the profile of the bevel under the geometry pane in object data properties. I need to give a resolution of at least 1 to my bevel to get the desired squared result.

[image]

Do you have any other better way to model this ? I don't like the fact that I have to convert it to mesh than remove the additional non-required loops to keep it as low poly as possible. Also is there any way to add custom bevel profile presets ?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Why not design a bespoke bevel object with a clean square shape?

Comment: You're right that's a method I actually had forgot about that I also used on this. I think I'd just like a simpler tool with length and width sliders like in 3ds max. With geo nodes maybe I could do this ?

Comment: Geometry nodes will allow doing that easily, currently there isn't any method to easily control width and height of a bevel object. Until then see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58564/curve-bevel-function-scale