# Why is the scale of the Bezier Bevel so massive on Curves? how can I scale effectively?

Tags: bezier-curves

I'm struggling to model with curves today. I can't seem to scale the curve without making the object curve so tiny I can't even see it?
[image]

To get the curve size I want, the target object is a speck on the screen.
[image]

Has this been updated since last I used it? 2020 How do I scale without having a speck on my screen?

Comment: Can you upload the blend file to https://blend-exchange.com/ ?

Comment: Check the radius of your bevelled curve's control-points, in Edit Mode.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58564/curve-bevel-function-scale/58567

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you scale a curve, it also scales it's vertex radius.
And vertex radius affects bevel size.

Simply tab to edit mode and set *Mean Radius* back to 1.

[image]

Comment: Excellent thanks @jachym, super helpful.... what a nice little place to hide that setting.

Comment: no problem :). The first time i got stuck on this I also went here to get help :))

Comment: Does anyone know how to do this with, say 150 curves at once?

Comment: Hi @Hector :). Consider asking this as a new question, you can link this one to provide context. People won't see your comment here, this is an older thread ;).