# why is my curve bevel non-uniform?

Tags: bezier-curves

As you can see, using the bevel option on my curve results in this irregular shape, what am I missing, please?
Thank you.

[image]

Comment: have you applied the scale in Object mode?

Comment: Perhaps the vertex radius is causing it? https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/250716/78972

Comment: Thank you.  Fun fact: I had hit ctrl+A and then "all transforms", and blender responded with "Rotation and Location can't apply to a 2d curve" and I thought "Ah well, it must have applied the other transforms, like object scale." But actually, it had not! So I had to apply scale (and only scale) one more time, and it seems a lot better! @moonboots

Comment: @JachymMichal Thanks. Not the cause of this problem, actually, but I was about to post another question on vertex radius, and you saved me that.