# Curve modifier squashes the mesh into a tiny cable

Tags: mesh, modifiers, bezier-curves, curve-modifier

I have a basic cylinder, I'm using it with array and curve modifiers.
When I assign the curve modifier the mesh does not retain it's size but is squashed into a thin wire.
Why does this happen?

PS: I have used this method again and again with working results, it's just not working for this particular curve.

Images:

1. Mesh in edit mode(original size)
2. Mesh with curve in effect(squashed into a wire)
3. Curve in object mode
4. Curve in edit mode

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did u apply scale & rotation?

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/250716/78972

Comment: Applied scaleNrot