# How to taper part of a tube

Tags: edit-mode

I want to create a 3D object of a street lamp pole - the tall ones seen on highways. The pole will be tapered about 3/4 of its length and the top 1/4 all the same diameter at the top of the tapered part.
I can create an octagon tube and then taper it however unsure how to taper just the bottom part and the top part the same 'diameter' as the top of the tapered part. I will also need to 'bend' the top part but think I have that worked out ok.I Also have the lamp housing worked out but just need to work out how taper part of my octagon tube with the top section not tapered. See attached image.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58564/curve-bevel-function-scale/58567 #4

Comment: Thanks for the link. I assume I would be using 'point' 5 however I am still 'in the dark'. If I start with a cylinder, how to I set points/vertices so that I can 'control' a part of the total cylinder? Do I apply a cut first? Regardless of the fact that I have worked out how to bend the cylinder and create it in the shape of an octagon I am still a 'newbie'.

Answer (score 0):

[image]I have worked out the method and nothing like what has been suggested. Mesh ADD Cylinder, select OBJECT mode, select top FACE of cylinder, SCALE to a smaller diameter (this results in a tapered cylinder), select top FACE (already selected), use EXTRUDE tool and add length. Beautiful (if I say so myself). I have inserted image of result in question.