# Edit the resulting NURBS surface of a bevelling

Tags: edit-mode, bevel, nurbs-surface

These are the editing handles for a NURBS torus:

[image]

Let's say I want to create a "torus" on an arbitrary NURBS curve. I read I need to use the bevel feature:

[image]
[image]

*(by the way, I was expecting a smaller extrusion, given the small circle)*

If I edit the resulting solid, I get the UV editing handles of the path:

[image]

Instead, now I want to edit **also** the whole object, having the handles like the first torus above. I looked at the "convert" options, but I found nothing useful.

What I have to do in order to edit it as the resulting NURBS surface, without loosing the possibility to edit the initial curve?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58564/curve-bevel-function-scale

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos interesting, even it's not the same kind of manipulation I've in mind, actually

Comment: By the way, why in the examples the extruded shape maintains its size, while in my case doesn't?

Comment: My answer there is explaining all the reasons and methods to control the size of the extruded shape.