# Coil with taper & thickness change

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to make a coil that varies in radius and thickness over its length.  Imagine a snake, thin at the tail & head, fatter in the middle, wrapping itself around a tapered cone.

It seems like it should be possible with mods, but my Blender skills are rudimentary, so I need hand holding.

Any ideas very welcome.  Thanks.

Jon

Comment: Would recommend this answer from Duarte on curve tapering - https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/58567/110840

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58564/curve-bevel-function-scale

Comment: Thanks, I'll give them a go.