# Extrude along curve

Tags: bezier-curves, bevel, extrude

This is my first time using blender, and I'm looking to create a long prism with no more than eight edges to the end faces, that also twists and tapers. I took a Maya class a few years ago, and in Maya there was an option to extrude a face along a bezier curve, and there were sliders for adjusting taper, number of divisions along the length, twist, etc. I've tried eye-dropping and object with a bezier's bevel menu— is there a way to get a mesh from that with vertices and edge loops, as opposed to the smoothed tube it gives on default? Or is there another way to do this without just creating a long cube and rotating edge loops manually?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58564/curve-bevel-function-scale/