# How to add a uniform complex shape to a high poly geometry?

Tags: extrude, bevel

Can anyone help me understand how to add this kind of ring geometry for a high-poly mesh:

[image]

[image]

[image]

It almost feels like the author simply selected an edge loop on a high poly mesh and applied some action that bevels the loop and smoothly extrudes (spins?pops?) the newly created loops. Can anyone tell me how that can be done?

Comment: If I had to do it: each part modeled separately but having the same amount of divisions, then delete edge loops on each and finally bridge edge loops between them. Can be also tried: a grid fill from the surrounding mesh.

Comment: I am a newbie in blender: how do you superposition or align separate parts perfectly?

Comment: Could you had an image showing how the corners are done?

Comment: I've added an image but it's just the same dude - solidified edge loop.

Comment: I think I've got it, there is no 1-action way but there is a simple solution:
http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/8305/35964

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be obtained with a subdivision surface modifier, starting from a simple shape:

[image]

Here we can make it using a mirror modifier on X, Y, Z.

The base shape is as shown below: just the profile repeated/rotated at the extremities and at the corner.

With the mirror and the subdivision surface, we obtain this:

[image]

Now, refine the profile adding two loop cuts and grabbing down the border:

[image]

[image]

**Edit** following the comments, if you want to do it from an already modeled base shape:

- In edit mode, duplicate an edge loop (note that if the subdivision is already applied on the object, that's changing nothing)
- Separate it
- Convert it to curve
- Give some bevel to the curve
- Set the curve 'U' resolution to 1 (that will keep the same amount of vertices around as the original)
- Convert back to mesh

After that, to do: remove some edges loops in the inner part in both objects, join them, and bridge edge loops between them.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, i upvoted it, but my question was specific: I want to add to a detail to a high-poly mesh. Cool thechnique with mirroring though.

Comment: @cubrman. You should rephrase your question: reading your comment, it's quite different. If I understand you well "starting from 'this mesh', how to construct a border like 'this'?"...

Comment: you are right, I should have worded it better. Sorry about that. Fixed the wording.

Comment: @cubrman, no need to sorry. Answer is updated.