# Fill out the stick man

Tags: modifiers, extrude

I have a very simple stick man in Blender 2.8, I'd like to give him somewhat more of a rounded body. So, instead of the edges and vertices he is made of now, I'd like to give him thicker limbs and a torso. I'd though I could do that by sort of skinning him.

But that doesn't work. It becomes very clunky, not even recognisable as a stick man anymore.

Then I tried converting him to a curve and beveling that. But, that doesn't play well with the Y-shapes, leading to a non-symmetric shape.

How would I go about generating a somewhat tubular body for him?[image: Stick man, just a set of vertices and edges]

Edit: the suggestion was to look atblender.stackexchange.com/questions/8300/how-to-solidify-edges, that doesn't work as the curve is, I believe, not closed, leading to unwanted distortions, as can be seen in this example:

[image: Via the curve method]

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8300/how-to-solidify-edges

Comment: That doesn't work, because of the curve in the Y - joints. I'll add a picture to illustrate.

Comment: Linked question doesn't consist of only one way rather than 2 instead. Skin modifier is the way I generally was referring to.

Comment: Are you trying to do this tutorial?
https://youtu.be/wCI8ZbTBP1w?t=100

Comment: did you try using a skin modifier and a subsurf modifier?

Comment: Not trying the youtu.be/wCI8ZbTBP1w?t=100 tutorial. I am actually looking for a far simpler figures. A true stick figure, consisting of 5 sticks.

The skin and subsurf, gives a result, but that is not close to what I want alas.

Comment: @Millard You should explain those steps as an answer.