# Tube around mesh wireframe

Tags: mesh

I need to generate a mesh where I can take the wireframe edges of the mesh and apply a shape to them so that the resulting mesh is long rods across those wireframe edges with the cross-section being of the shape I applied.

Below is similar to what I would like to do but instead of this, I would like it with a cylinder (or any shape if possible)

[image]

I rather like gandalf3's answer above the one from Coburn as I need to export this effect to Unity, so I rather have a real mesh above a visualization in blender.

I include both as correct answers

[Create a rounded wireframe?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2838/create-a-rounded-wireframe)

[How can I render an edge only mesh as solid lines?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3149/how-can-i-render-an-edge-only-mesh-as-solid-lines)

Comment: Is it possible you could provide a reference image of the effect you'd like to achieve?

Comment: I hope the image helps to clarify my question.

Comment: @user2888973 do you want the edges to look like tubes?

Comment: Yes I'd like to be able to make them any form I like like a Bevel object to a curve... sorry I don't know what option I am looking for

Comment: Similar to what you're looking for but not a complete answer to your question. http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3149/how-can-i-render-an-edge-only-mesh-as-solid-lines

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/2838/599

Comment: This is *not* a duplicate of [this question](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3149/how-can-i-render-an-edge-only-mesh-as-solid-lines). The linked question is asking how to *render* edges as lines, while this question is asking how to make actual tubes out of geometry around edges.

Comment: Could you use the Wireframe modifier?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Starting in edit mode you want to delete all faces from the mesh object <kbd>X</kbd>.

[image]

Then convert the mesh to a curve <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>

[image]

Now that you have a curve object you can add any bevel shape you want to it by editing a new curve object to the shape and set it as the bevel object.

[image]

As you may notice in that screenshot, the curve from mesh object may need some cleanup. A mesh object can branch out many time from one vertex where a curve is one continuous line, this can leave "loose ends" in the generated curve.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply... This is what I was asking for. thank you

Comment: Where is this button in Blender 2.8? I don't see "Curve from Mesh/Text" and Alt+C does nothing.

Comment: @AaronFranke the Alt-C shortcut has been removed. You can find *"Convert to"* in the object menu. Or press F3 and enter "conv" to see "Convert to" in the list.