# How to create poly cylinders on all edges easily?

Tags: modeling, edges

I have a low poly model that I am trying to modify to have a constructed look to it.

[image]

The look I am going for is similar to this where all edges are cylinders connecting the spherical vertices: (With the faces filled)

[image]

I have managed to get the spheres at all vertices of my low poly model using duplicate but I need to get the cylindrical parts on all edges between the spheres to complete the look.

Is there a way to make this happen programatically/using functionality? I really don't want to have to do this manually.

This will be used in a game engine so needs to be geometry that can be imported so no magic rendering tricks unfortunately.

Comment: Why not just add a "Wireframe" Modifier to it without "Replace original" being checked?

Comment: It is much more controllable via the animation nodes Add-on or via Sverchok.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/2838/599

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Youd could clone your mesh with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> and add a wireframe modifier to it, that way the meshed are kept linked and in sync so modifications propagate.
Or as suggested by Samoth add the wireframe modifier without the option *Replace Original* so the underlaying mesh is kept visible

The *Wireframe modifier* does add a flat shaded grid with square section, so you may want to add a bevel modifier on top of it to make it smooth and cylindrical

[image: Wireframe Modifier]

Comment: Spot on. I am really new to this so that is magic thanks.

Comment: http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/436/what-to-do-with-questions-which-have-been-answered-in-comments ;-)

Comment: Don't worry, I appreciate your answer as well and UVed it. It adds some valuable information I didn't mention.

Answer (score 4):

Just add a *Wireframe* Modifier to it with *Replace Original* unchecked.

[image: Example]