# Wireframe modifier with intersection "nodes"

Tags: modifiers, wireframe

I want to learn how to add objects (in this case spheres) automatically at all the intersections of a wireframe modifier on an object.

I'm pretty new to Blender and wanting to use it to create some cool wireframes I can import into Illustrator and turn into line-art. I've had some success. But I'm trying to figure out how to add spherical nodes at the intersections of pipes when using the wireframe modifier. Like in this example. Is there another kind of modifier I should look at or try to understand? So far the model I'm working with is a banana. (see second attached image)

[image]

[image]

Comment: There's no modifier that does it yet. Use Python scripts.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52735/how-to-create-poly-cylinders-on-all-edges-easily/52737#52737

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be accomplished through instancing.

[image: Example render]

1. Create your object
2. Duplicate the object <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>
3. Add a wireframe modifier to the duplicated object
4. Parent the original object to the duplicated object: Select the original object first, then the duplicate and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, *Set Parent to > Object*.
5. Create a sphere object and scale it to the desired size.
6. Parent the sphere to the original object: Select the sphere first, then the object and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, *Set Parent to > Object*.
7. Select the original object and open the *Object* tab in the properties. In the *Instancing* panel enable instancing for *Verts* and disable *Render Instancer*

The instructions above create instances of the sphere at the vertex positions of the object and a wireframe version of it. The duplicate object is necessary because the wireframe modifier creates new geometry, which would be used by the instancing. This would result in spheres being placed at the vertices of the generated wireframe mesh instead of the original vertex positions.

You can download the example project below:

[image]

Comment: Robert, thanks!! Super pro answer!! 