# is there a modifier I can use to create this cage-like chair seat?

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, edit-mode, transforms

I'm trying to create this chair shape made from what looks like a cage.

[image: screenshot 1]

I've created the shape itself and made edges across the different faces. Afterward, I erase the faces and after being left with the edges only, I apply a skin modifier and it creates something along the lines of what I needed but not quite.

[image: scrrenshot 2]
[image: scrrenshot 3]

Is there a better way to make this shape? Should I make each edge a cylinder manually one at a time or are there skin modifier settings I can tweak? I've also thought about curves too.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIF](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)

Comment: @Duarte Farrajota Ramos When I try to post pictures it says that my images are too big to upload, that they're over 2 MB. They're screenshots

Comment: a 1920x1080 JPG screenshot from Blender with a reasonably detailed model is under 300KB and a PNG one is around 1.5 MB here so I'd find some smaller images!

Comment: @JohnEason From blender? I'm taking them with my MacBook. How would you do that in blender exactly? I also duplicated the screenshot and changed the file extension of the duplicate image from png to jpg and the size didnt change.

Comment: Adding a sub division surface on top of the skin modifier might get closer to what you're looking for, or [using a wireframe modifier](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/144964/599).

Comment: Also you need to apply the scale of the object in Object mode so that the thickness is equal everywhere

Comment: @user9299960 You seem to have managed it now, but usually you'd use whatever imaging program a Mac uses to reduce the resolution or size of the image. Just changing the file extension won't usually work because the compression and format of the image within the file is different.

Comment: @user9299960: one very easy way to get a smaller screenshot is just by making the blender window smaller and then taking a screenshot with shift-command-4 -> then you can choose the rectangle for your screenshot.

Comment: @JohnEason: i have to agree with OP. I just tried it out. A "simple" screenshot takes 3.6 MB on a Macbook (M1) if you do it with the whole screen size - and i think the reason is because a Macbook by default save screenshots as PNG ... ;)

Comment: @Chris I'm glad that I use a PC in that case! :^)

Comment: @JohnEason: ;) i am pretty sure you can change that default behaviour - or just size it down - or change the file type (of course NOT by renaming ;) ) - or make a smaller screenshot...or...or...or ;)

Comment: More than likely, but I've never used a Mac of any sort so wouldn't know. :^)

Comment: The wireframe modifier did the trick I appreciate the help everyone! I will research how to change the original screenshot settings and also try to shrink the blender window for a smaller image for comparison.